# Obtener un Valor de un Array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ciclos

Saludos a todos, tengo el siguiente código JavaScript:

```
var Lista=[];

    $.getJSON("php/consultas/TraerDatos.php", function( data ) {
       $.each(data, function(id,value){
           var elemento = {
               'Proyecto':''+value['Proyecto'] +'',
               'Motivo':''+value['Motivo']+'' ,
               'Codigo': ''+value['Codigo']+'' ,
               'otro': ''+value['Motivo']+'' ,
               'Lugar': ''+value['Lugar']+''
       };

       Lista.push(elemento);
       });
   });
```

Y necesito sacar el valor 'Codigo' del array 'Lista' para asignarlo a otra variable

```
var temp = /* Asignación que no tengo clara hacer del objeto del array 
           Lista de su valor 'codigo' en la posición 0 */
```

solamente ese valor, así que supongo que no necesito recorrerlo con foreach, en el contexto de mi función todos estos elementos tienen el mismo valor en el código, sería obtenerlo de este array en la posición 0, lo he intentado pero no me funciona. ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de obtener dicho valor en este caso?

Como siempre estoy abierto a sus sugerencias y consejos. Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Sólo quieres recuperar el valor del atributo `Codigo` del primer elemento de la lista? Eso es así:

```
var temp = Lista.length ? Lista[0].Codigo : null;
```

Ahora, que si sólo quieres eso, y no vas a hacer nada con el resto de valores de la lista, también podías simplificar y hacer esto:

```
var codigo = null;
$.getJSON("php/consultas/TraerDatos.php", function(data) {
  if (data.length) {
    codigo = data[0].Codigo
  }
});
```

Comment: 1. No, es que la asignación del json la muestro en otro elemento de la página web, así que si lo necesito. 2. Esa asignación es exactamente lo que necesito. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.